# Java reflection, what class does the object have?

Tags: java, reflection

im trying to do some reflection on a applet.
things i found are some arrays of ints, strings, objects etc.

for example, if there was a field with an object[] and object[0].toString() = [I@7593c366
then i know its an integer array. but what if it says aa@98324ca33 is it's class then aa?
im using a classloader, so my first guess when i see this i need to load the aa class (part before the @, and use the object in it. but im not sure the part befor the @ is the class. can somebody say me this is right? or got other ideas?

thnx!

Comment: Why don't you just use `object[0].getClass()` ? Also, why would you need to load the class again? And you know that a class doesn't normally _contain_ objects, don't you? Thus _use the object in it_ is not quite accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use `toString()` for this - for one thing, it can have been overridden. As a straightforward example:

```
Object x = "aa@98324ca33";
String bogusClassName = x.toString();
```

You would clearly be wrong to think that `x` refers to an object of type `aa` here - it refers to a string.

You can find out the class of any object just by calling `getClass()` on it:

```
Object x = new SomeType();
Class<?> clazz = x.getClass();
```

It's not really clear what you're trying to do or where you're getting information from in the first place, but you *definitely* shouldn't be using `toString` to determine the class involved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the part before @ is the class fqn, but you should not rely on that. Object can override `toString()` and then your logic will fail.

Use `obj.getClass()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the class [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). Just call `getClass` on an object to retrieve its class instead of using the `toString` method

```
Object anObject = ... ;
Class<?> clazz = anObject.getClass();
```

If you want to check whether it is an array, you can use to [`Class#isArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray%28%29) method

```
clazz.isArray()
```

The other way around is also possible. If you have a `Class` instance, you can determine whether an object belongs to this class by using the [`Class#isInstance( Object )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method

```
clazz.isInstance( anObject );
```